# Is the trailer-question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I see [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/245/66) has a close-vote with the reason off-topic. I could join in and close-vote, but I miss at the moment the particular reason, why it is off-topic. The question is related to movies, so the very trivial check pass. If we regard this off-topic, it should be something, that our FAQ should contain. As the FAQ is in writing, we should be clear about it. Yes, Alonzo wrote into his FAQ-template trailer-analysis as off-topic. But he is also the one asking this question. So I think he want us to discuss this.

I personally have no opinion so far. I'm not much interested in this question, but I see so far no harm from it. So I could go either way. So should this question off-topic and then why? And if it should be on-topic, why should it?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I am the one who added the close vote. The question asks about the [unique selling point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_selling_proposition) of the trailer. This term does not stem from movies but marketing. The point of a trailer is to market the audience. A trailer is basically a commercial for the movie.</strike>

*Why should it be off-topic?*

Trailers do not add contribution to the understanding of the film. You cannot analyze a trailer, the mash-up of scenes is done by the distributor. Also trailers sometimes include footage that never appears in the movie. The point of that footage is mainly there for advertising purposes.

If you are analyzing scenes *individually* in a trailer, you are analyzing the movie, you are *not* analyzing the trailer.

I concede. You are both giving me a headache.

[image: Context]

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888?m=2647374#2647374

Comment: I'm not necessarily arguing for questions about trailers to be on-topic, but the fact that the footage is there for advertising purposes doesn't preclude it from the ability to be analyzed. You can definitely analyze the scenes included in a trailer - the fact that it's done by the distributor doesn't much matter; the fact that the choice of scenes shapes people's perceptions of the movie does.

Comment: @Laura There are no *full* scenes in a trailer. What purpose does analyzing the trailer of the film add to understand the film? None. I don't see why are you arguing my literal words and phrases, "You cannot analyze a trailer" within the context of understanding the movie, I hope this is understood. Yes you can analyze a single scene in a trailer because it's from the movie. You cannot analyze a trailer from start to end without throwing in some marketing.

Comment: @Laura The fact that this is from distributor does indeed matter or else I can just throw in that commercial about that one movie that went to DVD. Or that one commercial from ABC that threw together scenes on their own to have a preview for their TV movie special. A trailer is a commercial and it is an *indirect* work of the production team. In no way can I say, "Yes Mr.X Director definitely wanted to show scene 1 followed by scene 20 followed by scene 2 followed by scene 1 again"

Comment: @Laura Let me say this again just look at the following : *If you are analyzing scenes individually in a trailer, you are analyzing the movie, you are not analyzing the trailer*

Comment: Please don't throw definitions around @Mnementh Where did I say that I created the question to be a bad example? Please check the chatroom for context http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888?m=2647374#2647374 I asked a question after which someone asked about it on chat and we decided that maybe it wasn't a good fit after all so I placed a close vote. I am honestly tired of battling anyone anymore. I gave you an answer why the question was there and I gave you context http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1888?m=2647374#2647374 just *don't spread false accusations about me*  :|

Comment: OK, sorry. I misunderstood you for asking and then closing the question yourself. I'm deleting my comment before, as it adds nothing to the discussion.

Comment: The things that should stay in the discussion: Trailers aren't always be made by the Distributors, Iron Sky  can be a counterexample. And trailers can be used to set the expectations of the viewer and so influence the experience of watching the movie. Both doesn't mean, that trailers should be on-topic, but it should be considered on making the decision.

Answer (score 0):

Trailer questions should be on-topic if they relate to the movie side of things.

In my opinion, these would be acceptable questions: (none of these are good per se, but still on-topic)

> Which actor is in this trailer?
>
> Does this scene in the trailer actually happen in the film?
>
> When was this trailer released?

While questions relating to marketing are off-topic.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Aren't your examples just poor trivia questions? I fail to see the value in them

Comment: @IvoFlipse I don't see them as trivia questions, nor do I see them as good questions.

Comment: @Pubby if you don't see them as good questions, and if nobody else does, then they don't belong on this site. I personally also think these are trivia questions.

Comment: Sorry Pubby, I agree with Ivo here. These are some poor questions to show whether trailers should be on-topic. These are all trivial questions.

Comment: @Laura I see my examples as bad, but not the tag. We've only gotten 1 trailer question so far and it is very early to judge the quality of it. This question will be better answered in a several months.